# Shipment Tracking displays Error in DHL Easylog Module

Tags: magento-1.7, dhl, shipping-methods

I am using a DHL EasyLog Shipping Module

I use DHL International and DPD international Shipping and when I enter the shipping information on the Order I choose DHL  (Deprecated) and enter the tracking number.

On the customers end or admin end when I click on the tracking number it brings the Pop-Up up and gives the following:

Tracking Information

Tracking Number:  xxxxxxxxxx 
Carrier:   DHL (Deprecated)
Error:  Tracking information is currently not available. Please contact us for more information or email us at Support@.........

Please advise!

Answer (score 2):

So a wild guess is that this carrier method is not available or is actually deprecated. As the line in the file `/app/code/core/Mage/Usa/etc/config.xml` is as follows.

```
<specificerrmsg>This shipping method is currently unavailable. If you would like to ship using this shipping method, please contact us.</specificerrmsg>
```

Try using only the carrier with the code `dhl`and label `DHL` and not the `DHL (deprecated)` version.

*Note: there is an article from magento about installing the dhl deprecated if you need to use this version. http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/configure-dhl-shipping*